# Plupload Overall Progress issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I have below code in before upload event for a Plupload control in my aspx page which has three upload control for upload images. my problem is when "Validate_Img_File_Name.ashx" returns not success output and stop the specific file upload the overall progress bar and the progress percentage is not finishing at 100%. function "_updateTotalProgress:" in jquery.ui.plupload.js do the overall progress I guess, but I have no idea of how to overcome this issues since my knowledge of java is zero. how can I get the correct overall progress ? your help is highly appreciated.

```
BeforeUpload: function (up, file) {
    // Called right before the upload for a given file starts, can be used to cancel it if required
    //log('[BeforeUpload]', 'File: ', file);
    $.ajax({
        url: "../Validate_Img_File_Name.ashx",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'text',
        data: { filename: file.name },
        cache: false,
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data == "SUCCESS") {
            up.settings.url = '/bulk_img_uploader.ashx';
            file.status = plupload.UPLOADING;
            up.trigger("UploadFile", file);
            up.settings.url = '';
            log('File:', file, '- OK');
        } else {
            //alert(file.name + " " + "fail");
            up.stop();
            file.status = plupload.FAILED;

            up.trigger('QueueChanged');            //Line A
            up.trigger('UploadProgress', file);     // Line B

            up.start();
            log('File:', file, ' - ' + data);

            return false;
        }
    });
},
```